# Nextjs App reading configuration from Azure App Service

Tags: azure, docker, next.js, environment-variables, azure-appservice

We have a nextjs project which is build by docker and deploy into Azure App Service (container). We also setup configuration values within App Service and try to access it, however its not working as expected.

Few things we tried

- Restarting the App Service after adding new configuration
- removing .env file while building the docker image
- including .env file while building the docker image

[image]
Here's how we read try to read the environment variables within the App Service

```
  const env = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV;
  const A = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AS_VALUE;
```

Wondering if this can actually be done?
Just thinking something out loud below,

1. Since we're deploying the docker image within App Service's Container (Linux).. does that mean, the container can't pull the value from this environment variable?
2. Docker image already perform the `npm run build`, would that means the image is in static formed (build time). It will never ready from App Service configuration (runtime).

Comment: Hello @TommyLeong, Could you please refer this [**MS DOC**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-app-service-to-deploy-the-image-from-the-registry) and make sure that you have provided the  `WEBSITES_PORT` environment variable as expected by the app code.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT I'm not trying to set the websites_port, instead custom config and values. Thereafter access by my website itself via `process.env.variable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day or 2, I came up with an **alternative solution** by passing the environment values in `Dockerfile` while building my project.

## TLDR

1. Pass your env values within dockerfile
2. Set all your env (dev, staging, prod, etc) var values in Pipeline variable.
3. Set a "settable" variable inside the Pipeline variable too, so you can set to build different environment while triggering your pipeline (eg, buildEnv)
4. Setup a bash script to perform variable text changing (eg, from `firebaseApiKey` to `DEVfirebaseApiKey` ) according to env received from `buildEnv`.
5. Use "replace token" task from Azure Pipeline to replace values inside `Dockerfile`
6. Build your docker image
7. Huaala~ now you get your environment specific build

## Details

Within your `Dockerfile` you can place your env variable like this

```
RUN NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV=#{env}# \ 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=#{firebaseApiKey}# \ 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=#{firebaseAuthDomain}# \ 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=#{firebaseProjectId}# \ 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=#{firebaseStorageBucket}# \ 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=#{firebaseMessagingSenderId}# \ 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID=#{firebaseAppId}# \ 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=#{firebaseMeasurementId}# \ 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=#{baseURL}# \ 
  npm run build
```

These values set (eg, baseURL, firebaseMeasurementId, etc) are only a placeholder, because we need to change them later with bash script according to the `buildEnv` we receive. *(buildEnv is settable when you trigger a build)*

Bash script sample as below. What it does is that it will look within your `Dockerfile` for the word `env` and change to `DEVenv` / `UATenv` / `PRODenv` based on what you're passing to `buildEnv`

```
#!/bin/bash
case $(buildENV) in
dev)
sed -i -e 's/env/DEVenv/g' ./Dockerfile
;;
uat)
sed -i -e 's/env/UATenv/g' ./Dockerfile
;;
prod)
sed -i -e 's/env/PROenvD/g' ./Dockerfile
;;
*)
echo -n "unknown"
;;
esac
```

When this is complete, your "environment specific" docker file is sort of created. Now we'll make use of the "replace token" task from Azure Pipeline to replace the values inside `Dockerfile`.  ***Make sure you have all your values setup in Pipeline Variable!*

Lastly all you may build your docker image and deploy :)